# Higher Order Component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

A/t to Docs, **HOC doesn't modify input component, nor does it use inheritance to copy its behavior. Rather, A HOC composes the original component by wrapping it in a container component.**

**In react, if props changes component is rerendered with newProps.**

Since In HOC we are passing props to both wrapper component test1 & test2 so they both should rerender on every props change. But this is not happening. In fact, test1 & test2 is rendered then test2 change props by state lifting up and rerendered. But test1 remains same.
Check the attached image.

I am interested to know how react-redux connect and react-router-dom withRouter actually work on every props change to store and rerender component.

[Real Problem on Github](https://github.com/Sarvesh18/MERN/tree/master/TestMERNApp/src_client/HOC)

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Test1 />
        <Test2 />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Component withHOC**

```js
class Test1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
          {
              this.props.test1
          }
          {
              this.props.test2
          }
      </div>
     )
  }
}
export default withHOC(Test1);
```

**Another Component withHOC**

```js
class Test2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {
            this.props.test1
        }
        {
            this.props.test2
        }
        <button type='button' onClick={()=>this.props.update('test')}>Update </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default withHOC(Test2);
```

**Higher Order Component**

```js
function withHOC(WrappedComponent) {
  class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          test1: 'test1',
          test2: 'test2'
      }
    }
    update = (u) => {
      this.setState({
          test2: u 
      })
    }
    render() {
      const test1 = this.state.test1;
      const test2 = this.state.test2;
      return (<WrappedComponent test1={test1} test2={test2} update={this.update}/>);
    }
  }
  return Test;
}
export default withHOC;
```

[Log of Life Cycle Methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m50kP.png)

Comment: Where's `withHOC`? What prop exactly is changing?

Comment: Update withHOC Code. On button click, setState update state and that state is passed as props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have failed to actually ask a question here - the title of this post should be rewritten in order to actually ask something.

Am I correct in saying that you're trying to use a HOC to share state between two components? And then expecting an update in `<Test2 />` to cause an update in `<Test1 />`, because `props.test2` on `<Test2 />` has changed?

If so, this is the wrong way to think of HOCs. Think of HOCs as **decorating** components with particular properties or behaviours. The use of `withHOC` detailed in your question doesn't say "let any component wrapped in `withHOC` access the single piece of state defined in this HOC", it says "any component wrapped in `withHOC` should have its own state defined by the functions given in this HOC".

So wrapping both components, and then having state in `<Test2 />` change, will ONLY change state in that particular component.

If you want an update in `<Test2 />` to cause an update in `<Test1 />`, then this must be done using the state of a parent component (i.e. `<Test />`).